# How to handle various units in a single attribute / feature using Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-manipulation

I have a dataset, on which i am working on Data Cleaning part, where one of the attribute or feature is having the values with various units. for example some of the values are as follow.
1 kg; 6 LB; 900 gms; 32 oz; etc.
If i use the standard scaler then it will not be fair as the values and their units are different, so cannot treat them as is.
Please do suggest how to handle such data.

Comment: Please post a sample of the data and a sample of desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will recommend to change the different value to same unit first of all. For example, you can make all the value to kg or whatever suits best for you, and then perform the standard scale.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All, I did some research and found that i need to convert the various units into standard units and which follow internation norms referred to SI Units https://www.nist.gov/pml/weights-and-measures/metric-si/si-units , and same suggestion has given by @sharmajee499.
Moving ahead with this approach.. though this is going to be a lot of manual code, but seems there is no direct short and easy way.
Please do post if have any better solution.